# angular list contains elements but length is 0

Tags: angular, typescript, http, asynchronous

I make a http get request using the following code as seen below

```
export class Covid19Service {
  baseUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSummary() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'summary').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  getCountry() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'dayone/country/ie/status/confirmed');
  }

}
```

I then parse the data into a list in the getCountry() method

```
export class BarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  dailyTotalConfirmed: number[] = [];
  dailyNewConfirmed: number[] = [];

  constructor(private covid19: Covid19Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountry();
    this.calculateDailyNewConfirmed();
    console.log(this.dailyTotalConfirmed);
    console.log(this.dailyNewConfirmed);
  }

  getSummary() {
    return this.covid19.getSummary();
  }

  getCountry() {
    this.covid19.getCountry()
    .subscribe(data => {
      const covid = Object.keys(data);

      for (const key of covid) {
        const cases = data[key].Cases;
        this.dailyTotalConfirmed.push(cases);
      }
    });
  }

  calculateDailyNewConfirmed() {
    const data = this.dailyTotalConfirmed;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      const casesToday = data[i];
      const casesTomorrow = data[i + 1];

      this.dailyNewConfirmed.push(Math.abs(casesTomorrow - casesToday));
    }
  }

}
```

when the calculateDailyNew() method is called, the for loop within that method does not execute as the length of the list is 0 even though when I console.log() the list there are elements in the list.
What have I done wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without running the code locally, it looks like `calculateDailyNewConfirmed()` is run before `getCountry()` finishes.

You'll have to set it up so `calculateDailyNewConfirmed()` runs only after `getCountry()` has received data back from the API. There are better ways, but the simplest to explain and implement would be to rename `getCountry()` to something like `getCountryAndCalculateDailyNewConfirmed()` and just make that call inside the subscribe block:

```
getCountryAndCalculateDailyNewConfirmed() {
this.covid19.getCountry()
.subscribe(data => {
  const covid = Object.keys(data);

  for (const key of covid) {
    const cases = data[key].Cases;
    this.dailyTotalConfirmed.push(cases);
  }
  this.calculateNewDailyConfirmed();
});
}
```

Hopefully that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`calculateDailyNewConfirmed` is called earlier than `subscribe` gets its value.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountry(); // <- starts request
    this.calculateDailyNewConfirmed(); // <- checks even request wasn't finished.
  }
```

A possible solution is to move `this.calculateDailyNewConfirmed()` in subscription of `getCountry`.